# Reactive Tailwind class with props on Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tailwind-css

I've tried using a reusable component on vue js like pass props class name. In my case, I'm using tailwind css.  How can I pass class name using props?

this is my code

```
<template lang="pug">
  router-link.button-filled(
      :to="routeName"
      :title="title"
      :class="customClass"
    )
    | {{ title }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    routeName: { default: "/", type: String },
    title: { default: "Button", type: String },
    size: { default: "md", type: String },
    backgroundColor: { default: "red-500", type: String },
    borderColor: { default: "red-500", type: String }
  },
  computed: {
    customClass() {
      return [
        "bg-" + this.backgroundColor,
        "border-" + this.borderColor
      ];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This is my **tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'fst-',
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And this is my **master.sass**

```
@tailwindcss base

@tailwindcss components
@import "./components/button-filled"
@import "./components/button-outlined"

@tailwindcss utilities
```

This is my result after I pass class using props.  Nothing changed but class success loaded on html attribute.

[image]

Comment: please share your tailwind.config and main css file

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim Welcome back, how are you :),

 
I've updated my question with tailwind.config.js and master.sass Thanks :)

Comment: place `@tailwindcss utilities` after `@tailwindcss components`

Comment: Hi @BoussadjraBrahim, still wont work, i've tried to use prefix on return but still same

Answer (score 7):

Few things I noticed:

1. You specified a custom prefix in your `tailwind.config.js`. That means all your tailwind classes should be prefixed with `fst-`. For example, `text-green-500` will be `fst--text-green-500` in your case.
2. You're concatenating class names in a way that will be ignored by PurgeCSS. When building your CSS for production, PostCSS goes through all your files and look for Tailwind class names according to your Tailwind config and remove all unused class names. Therefore, you should write your class names in full instead of concatenating them when using Tailwind.

Excerpt from the Tailwind documentation under [Optimizing for Production](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/optimizing-for-production).

[image: Excerpt from Tailwind CSS documentation]

Comment: Hi @Mysterywood, yes of course i use the prefix on my sass file like these

`.button-filled
  @apply fst-border-2` its work as well

, but my problem is adding new class and not rendered by tailwind